# How do I convert React API data to props for use in other components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been stuck on this for awhile now and I can't wrap my head around what I need to do with this data to be able to use it in other components. I'm able to render the data as expected but others tell me to construct the data in a function to be able to call it as props like `props.name` or `props.whatever`. But my issue is also that the API data doesn't classify by text like name, but rather by id's.

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "3": {
        "value": 177
      },
      "6": {
        "value": "2220 Three Kings "
      },
      "40": {
        "value": "In Progress"
      },
      "80": {
        "value": 38295.47
```

So whenever I tried to use this method I get errors. I'm also unsure on how to actually change my code to assign each field to it's own prop like title or amount. I've tried researching all over and haven't had any luck.

Here is my API call that is currently rendering data:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

let headers = {
  'QB-Realm-Hostname': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX.quickbase.com',
  'User-Agent': 'FileService_Integration_V2.1',
  'Authorization': 'QB-USER-TOKEN XXXXX_XXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};

class JobsTableApi extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }    

  fetchData = () => {    
     let body = {"from":"bpz99ram7","select":[3,6,80,81,82,83,86,84,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,101,103,104,105,106,107,109,111,113,115,120,123,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,477,479,480,481],"where": "{40.CT. 'In Progress'}","sortBy":[{"fieldId":6,"order":"ASC"}],"groupBy":[{"fieldId":40,"grouping":"equal-values"}],"options":{"skip":0,"top":0,"compareWithAppLocalTime":false}}

    fetch('https://api.quickbase.com/v1/records/query', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }).then(response => response.json())
      .then( data => this.setState({ data })
      );
    }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;

      if (data === null) return 'Loading Job Data...  ';

    return (
      <ul>
        {Object.keys(data["data"]).map(item => 
          <div key = {item.id}>
            <h2>
              Id: {data["data"][item][3].value} -- {data["data"][item][6].value}
              <br />
              {data["data"][item][40].value}
            </h2>
            <h5>Overall Project Totals:</h5>
              <p>Adj Contract Amount: ${Math.round(data["data"][item][80].value)}</p>
              <p>Design Hours: {Math.round(data["data"][item][88].value)},</p>
              <p>Design Amount: ${Math.round(data["data"][item][91].value)},</p>
              <p>SubRough Hours: {Math.round(data["data"][item][92].value)},</p>
              <p>SubRough Amount: ${Math.round(data["data"][item][95].value)},</p>
              <p>Rough Hours: {Math.round(data["data"][item][96].value)},</p>
              <p>Rough Amount: ${Math.round(data["data"][item][98].value)},</p>
              <p>Finish Hours: {Math.round(data["data"][item][104].value)},</p>
              <p>Finish Amount: ${Math.round(data["data"][item][107].value)},</p>
              <p>Close Hours: {Math.round(data["data"][item][477].value)},</p>
              <p>Close Amount: ${Math.round(data["data"][item][480].value)},</p>
              <p>CURRENT/ACTUAL Hours: {Math.round(data["data"][item][479].value)},</p>
              <p>CURRENT/ACTUAL Amount: ${Math.round(data["data"][item][224].value)}</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

export default JobsTableApi;
```

Any help or suggestions on How I can use this data, move it over to props with the numeric ID's and be able to call these fields on my other components would be greatly appreciated.

My idea is that I already have other components that have line charts for areas that I just want to populate with these fields that I'm already getting with this code, I just don't know how to convert to props with Id's and be able to use that in my other components.

***UPDATE:***
I've attempted this multiple times and either get nothing to render, or errors that props or data is undefined. I also console.log(props) and see `caller , callee , and arguments properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them.`
I've moved the API call file directly under src, and my Title.js file where I'm trying to move the data is in src>components>header>Title.js.

**Title.js:**

```
import { React, Component } from 'react'
import '../../JobsTableApi';

class Title extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>
      {Object.keys(this.props.data["data"]).map(item => 
        <div key = {item.id}>
          <h1>
            {this.props.name}
          </h1>
        </div>
        )
      }
      </h1>
    )
  }
}

export default Title
```

**API Call:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Title from './components/header/Title.js'

let headers = {
  'QB-Realm-Hostname': 'XXXXXXXXXXXX.quickbase.com',
  'User-Agent': 'FileService_Integration_V2.1',
  'Authorization': 'QB-USER-TOKEN XXXX_XXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};

class JobsTableApi extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }    

  fetchData = () => {    
     let body = {"from":"bpz99ram7","select":[3,6,80,81,82,83,86,84,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,101,103,104,105,106,107,109,111,113,115,120,123,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,477,479,480,481],"where": "{40.CT. 'In Progress'}","sortBy":[{"fieldId":6,"order":"ASC"}],"groupBy":[{"fieldId":40,"grouping":"equal-values"}],"options":{"skip":0,"top":0,"compareWithAppLocalTime":false}}

    fetch('https://api.quickbase.com/v1/records/query', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }).then(response => response.json())
      .then( data => this.setState({ data })
      );
    }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;

      if (data === null) return 'Loading Job Data...  ';

    return (
      <ul>
        {Object.keys(data["data"]).map(item => 
          <div key = {item.id}>
            <h2>
              <Title name={this.state["data"][item][6].value} /> -- Id: {data["data"][item][3].value} 
              <br />
            {data["data"][item][40].value}
            </h2>
            <h5>Overall Project Totals:</h5>
              <p>Adj Contract Amount: ${Math.round(data["data"][item][80].value)},</p>
              <p>Design Hours: {Math.round(data["data"][item][88].value)},</p>
              <p>Design Amount: ${Math.round(data["data"][item][91].value)},</p>
              <p>SubRough Hours: {Math.round(data["data"][item][92].value)},</p>
              <p>SubRough Amount: ${Math.round(data["data"][item][95].value)},</p>
              <p>Rough Hours: {Math.round(data["data"][item][96].value)},</p>
              <p>Rough Amount: ${Math.round(data["data"][item][98].value)},</p>
              <p>Finish Hours: {Math.round(data["data"][item][104].value)},</p>
              <p>Finish Amount: ${Math.round(data["data"][item][107].value)},</p>
              <p>Close Hours: {Math.round(data["data"][item][477].value)},</p>
              <p>Close Amount: ${Math.round(data["data"][item][480].value)},</p>
              <p>CURRENT/ACTUAL Hours: {Math.round(data["data"][item][479].value)},</p>
              <p>CURRENT/ACTUAL Amount: ${Math.round(data["data"][item][224].value)}</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

export default JobsTableApi;
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"props"_ here? In [React, props are the values you provide to components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) but I don't think that's what you mean. Could you please provide some concrete examples of what it is you're trying to do and explain how it's not working as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly basically you want other components on your project to be able to access the state found within the JobsTableApi class component right? Since that state is the one containing the fetched data? If that is the case then just create the other components as you would eg:

```
class OtherComponent extends Component { constructor(props) {
super(props); } 
}
```

so then to access the state from other components without triggering a compile error just use the argument props so that everything looks the same as the class component but just with the added props before it for instance this is your code for the JobsTableApi:

```
{Object.keys(data["data"]).map(item => 
      <div key = {item.id}>
```

The access this on new component just use props for instance:

```
{Object.keys(this.props.data["data"]).map(item => 
      <div key = {item.id}>
```

Then the last step would be to go to your JobsTableApi and import the new component and pass props to it:

```
import OtherComponent from "./OtherComponent";
```

Then to your render method you could add it to be used around as such:

```
render ( return ( <OtherComponent data={this.state.data} /> ) );
```

Lastly you could also swap this process and instead use your JobsTableApi on the new component you would just need to lift the state to do this or in other words fetch the data on the new component instead.

Comment: lmk if this made sense or if your question was something else maybe i can help you out. Also just as another person mentioned you could also use redux to achieve this in a more scalable way. But is not mandatory

Comment: Yes, so I'm trying to access that data in my JobsTableApi in another component, and then I also have another Api call just like it for multiple components. the 'other' components are some Line charts that I'm building, one to show overall job progress with the data shown above, and the others are corresponding departments within that job. I'll give this a shot to see if I can share the data to the other components. Thanks Brian!

Comment: Anytime hope it works. So long as you keep the state on the top level component you can keep passing it down to child components. Good luck!

Comment: edited to fix code missing on the render method passing props section of answer

Comment: Let me ask you, the this.props.data line is to be used on my 'other' component where I want to send this data? Then Import that 'other' component back to my JobsTableApi and add the render method to set that component to the state? I'm I following you correctly on this?

Comment: this.props is used on the other component then you import that component to your main component where the state is held. And you assign the needed property by using the name you used in this.props. For instance if in the other component you wrote your logic as: this.props.data then you would go ahead and assign the prop to component being imported as data={this.data}.

Comment: Its tricky to understand this at first when diving into ReactJs. I think the following video could help clarify: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ICmMVfKjEuo

Comment: I got ya. Thanks Brian!

Comment: I'm also getting data undefined when using ```{Object.keys(this.props.data["data"]).map(item => 
      <div key = {item.id}>``` haven't been able to get these to be able to be used on other components.

Comment: Would you have a suggestion on how to convert {data["data"][item][6].value} to be used in the call on my other component? Your recommendation was {this.state.data} but I also don't want all the data, just that one field that is the Title. Not sure how to rewrite my code to accommodate this.